# Getting error when running python code on tensorflow-metal on Macbook pro M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have successfully installed tensorflow-metal on my Macbook pro M1 in a separate environment, but when I run the following sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
history = model.fit(
    train_images, 
    train_labels, 
    epochs=10, 
    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels)
)
```

I got these errors:

> 2021-10-10 09:26:08.398847: I
> tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of
> the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2) 2021-10-10
> 09:26:08.399120: W
> tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get
> CPU frequency: 0 Hz Epoch 1/10 2021-10-10 09:26:08.554082: I
> tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112]
> Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled. 2021-10-10
> 09:26:08.581 python[65936:4662219] -[MPSGraph
> adamUpdateWithLearningRateTensor:beta1Tensor:beta2Tensor:epsilonTensor:beta1PowerTensor:beta2PowerTensor:valuesTensor:momentumTensor:velocityTensor:maximumVelocityTensor:gradientTensor:name:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16a877460 2021-10-10
> 09:26:08.594 python[65936:4662219] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
> exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPSGraph
> adamUpdateWithLearningRateTensor:beta1Tensor:beta2Tensor:epsilonTensor:beta1PowerTensor:beta2PowerTensor:valuesTensor:momentumTensor:velocityTensor:maximumVelocityTensor:gradientTensor:name:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16a877460'
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation  0x00000001929a5320 __exceptionPreprocess + 240  1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001926d3c04 objc_exception_throw + 60    2   CoreFoundation 0x0000000192a34020
> -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0     3   CoreFoundation 0x0000000192907174 ***forwarding*** + 1444   4   CoreFoundation
> 0x0000000192906b20 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96     5
> libmetal_plugin.dylib 0x000000012e81a290
> _ZN12metal_plugin14MPSApplyAdamOpIfEC2EPNS_20OpKernelConstructionE + 656  6   libmetal_plugin.dylib 0x000000012e819ebc
> _ZN12metal_pluginL14CreateOpKernelINS_14MPSApplyAdamOpIfEEEEPvP23TF_OpKernelConstruction
>
> - 52  7   libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x00000001192545d4 _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_120KernelBuilderFactory6CreateEPNS_20OpKernelConstructionE
> - 88  8   libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x00000001192d6158 _ZN10tensorflow14CreateOpKernelENS_10DeviceTypeEPNS_10DeviceBaseEPNS_9AllocatorEPNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntimeEPNS_11ResourceMgrERKNSt3__110shared_ptrIKNS_14NodePropertiesEEEiPPNS_8OpKernelE
> - 784     9   libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x00000001194b12b8 _ZN10tensorflow21CreateNonCachedKernelEPNS_6DeviceEPNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntimeERKNSt3__110shared_ptrIKNS_14NodePropertiesEEEiPPNS_8OpKernelE
> - 272     10  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib 0x000000011945bc20 _ZN10tensorflow26FunctionLibraryRuntimeImpl12CreateKernelERKNSt3__110shared_ptrIKNS_14NodePropertiesEEEPNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntimeEPPNS_8OpKernelE
> - 600     11  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001194c6430 _ZN10tensorflow22ImmutableExecutorState10InitializeERKNS_5GraphE + 1192  12  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001194b1064
>   _ZN10tensorflow16NewLocalExecutorERKNS_19LocalExecutorParamsERKNS_5GraphEPPNS_8ExecutorE
> - 304     13  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001194bee6c _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_124DefaultExecutorRegistrar7Factory11NewExecutorERKNS_19LocalExecutorParamsERKNS_5GraphEPNSt3__110unique_ptrINS_8ExecutorENS9_14default_deleteISB_EEEE + 48  14  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001194bf7e8 _ZN10tensorflow11NewExecutorERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_19LocalExecutorParamsERKNS_5GraphEPNS0_10unique_ptrINS_8ExecutorENS0_14default_deleteISG_EEEE
> - 92  15  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000011945e278 _ZN10tensorflow26FunctionLibraryRuntimeImpl10CreateItemEPPNS0_4ItemE + 2676  16  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000011945f06c
>   _ZN10tensorflow26FunctionLibraryRuntimeImpl3RunERKNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyN4absl12lts_202103244SpanIKNS_6TensorEEEPNSt3__16vectorIS8_NSB_9allocatorIS8_EEEENSB_8functionIFvRKNS_6StatusEEEE
> - 676     17  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000011946d0c0 _ZNK10tensorflow29ProcessFunctionLibraryRuntime14RunMultiDeviceERKNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyPNSt3__16vectorIN4absl12lts_202103247variantIJNS_6TensorENS_11TensorShapeEEEENS5_9allocatorISC_EEEEPNS6_INS5_10unique_ptrINS0_11CleanUpItemENS5_14default_deleteISI_EEEENSD_ISL_EEEENS5_8functionIFvRKNS_6StatusEEEENSP_IFSQ_RKNS0_21ComponentFunctionDataEPNS0_12InternalArgsEEEE
> - 2640    18  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x0000000119470098 _ZNK10tensorflow29ProcessFunctionLibraryRuntime3RunERKNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyN4absl12lts_202103244SpanIKNS_6TensorEEEPNSt3__16vectorIS8_NSB_9allocatorIS8_EEEENSB_8functionIFvRKNS_6StatusEEEE
> - 2012    19  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x0000000119470868 _ZNK10tensorflow29ProcessFunctionLibraryRuntime7RunSyncERKNS_22FunctionLibraryRuntime7OptionsEyN4absl12lts_202103244SpanIKNS_6TensorEEEPNSt3__16vectorIS8_NSB_9allocatorIS8_EEEE + 160   20  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c175538 _ZN10tensorflow19KernelAndDeviceFunc3RunEPNS_19ScopedStepContainerERKNS_15EagerKernelArgsEPNSt3__16vectorIN4absl12lts_202103247variantIJNS_6TensorENS_11TensorShapeEEEENS6_9allocatorISD_EEEEPNS_19CancellationManagerERKNS9_8optionalINS_25EagerRemoteFunctionParamsEEERKNSK_INS_17ManagedStackTraceEEE
> - 516     21  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c13fd44 _ZN10tensorflow18EagerKernelExecuteEPNS_12EagerContextERKN4absl12lts_2021032413InlinedVectorIPNS_12TensorHandleELm4ENSt3__19allocatorIS6_EEEERKNS3_8optionalINS_25EagerRemoteFunctionParamsEEERKNS7_10unique_ptrINS_15KernelAndDeviceENS_4core15RefCountDeleterEEEPNS_14GraphCollectorEPNS_19CancellationManagerENS3_4SpanIS6_EERKNSD_INS_17ManagedStackTraceEEE + 372   22  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c1463a8 _ZN10tensorflow11ExecuteNode3RunEv + 396     23  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c481748 _ZN10tensorflow13EagerExecutor11SyncExecuteEPNS_9EagerNodeE + 172    24  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c13f880 _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_117EagerLocalExecuteEPNS_14EagerOperationEPPNS_12TensorHandleEPi
> - 1976    25  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c13da28 _ZN10tensorflow12EagerExecuteEPNS_14EagerOperationEPPNS_12TensorHandleEPi
> - 296     26  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014bda2b88 _ZN10tensorflow14EagerOperation7ExecuteEN4absl12lts_202103244SpanIPNS_20AbstractTensorHandleEEEPi
> - 192     27  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x000000014c17b910 _ZN10tensorflow21CustomDeviceOpHandler7ExecuteEPNS_27ImmediateExecutionOperationEPPNS_30ImmediateExecutionTensorHandleEPi
> - 468     28  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x00000001489c7f1c TFE_Execute + 80     29  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
>   0x0000000148944934
>   _Z24TFE_Py_ExecuteCancelableP11TFE_ContextPKcS2_PN4absl12lts_2021032413InlinedVectorIP16TFE_TensorHandleLm4ENSt3__19allocatorIS7_EEEEP7_objectP23TFE_CancellationManagerPNS5_IS7_Lm2ESA_EEP9TF_Status
> - 616     30  _pywrap_tfe.so                      0x000000011a6ea4c0 *ZN10tensorflow32TFE_Py_ExecuteCancelable_wrapperERKN8pybind116handleEPKcS5_S3_S3_PNS_19CancellationManagerES3* + 160    31  _pywrap_tfe.so                      0x000000011a71b220 _ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZL25pybind11_init__pywrap_tfeRNS_7module_EE4$*44NS_6objectEJRKNS_6handleEPKcSA_S8_S8_S8_EJNS_4nameENS_5scopeENS_7siblingEEEEvOT_PFT0_DpT1_EDpRKT2_ENUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_8__invokeESR*
> - 184     32  _pywrap_tfe.so                      0x000000011a6fd16c *ZN8pybind1112cpp_function10dispatcherEP7_objectS2_S2* + 3216    33  python                              0x00000001043e58cc
>   cfunction_call_varargs + 292  34  python
>   0x00000001043e4f50 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 640     35  python
>   0x00000001044fa3e0 call_function + 680    36  python
>   0x00000001044f6ebc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29472   37  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    38  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   39  python
>   0x00000001044fa348 call_function + 528    40  python
>   0x00000001044f6fac _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29712   41  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    42  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   43  python
>   0x00000001043e991c method_vectorcall + 156    44  python
>   0x00000001044fa348 call_function + 528    45  python
>   0x00000001044f6fac _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29712   46  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    47  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   48  python
>   0x00000001043e991c method_vectorcall + 156    49  python
>   0x00000001044fa348 call_function + 528    50  python
>   0x00000001044f6fac _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29712   51  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    52  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   53  python
>   0x00000001043e4b84 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 132   54  python
>   0x00000001043e6cc4 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 156   55  python
>   0x000000010445a774 slot_tp_call + 296     56  python
>   0x00000001043e56e8 PyObject_Call + 312    57  python
>   0x00000001044f714c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30128   58  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    59  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   60  python
>   0x00000001043e9a88 method_vectorcall + 520    61  python
>   0x00000001043e54c0 PyVectorcall_Call + 120    62  python
>   0x00000001044f714c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30128   63  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    64  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   65  python
>   0x00000001043e4c1c _PyObject_FastCallDict + 284   66  python
>   0x00000001043e6cc4 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 156   67  python
>   0x000000010445a774 slot_tp_call + 296     68  python
>   0x00000001043e4f50 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 640     69  python
>   0x00000001044fa3e0 call_function + 680    70  python
>   0x00000001044f6ebc _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29472   71  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    72  python
>   0x00000001043e5f10 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 236   73  python
>   0x00000001043e991c method_vectorcall + 156    74  python
>   0x00000001044fa348 call_function + 528    75  python
>   0x00000001044f6fac _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29712   76  python
>   0x00000001044ef584 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3340    77  python
>   0x000000010454c0b0 PyRun_InteractiveOneObjectEx + 1196    78  python
>   0x00000001045488d0 PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 540   79  python
>   0x000000010454863c PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 72  80  python
>   0x00000001045710fc Py_RunMain + 3568  81  python
>   0x00000001045720a8 pymain_main + 1244     82  python
>   0x00000001043bc1e0 main + 56  83  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000192848f54 start + 4 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException zsh: abort      python

I cannot fix this error, please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: the code you are trying to run is pretty basic, surprised with the error not sure if this is M1 issue/  would you pls add these details,  `tf.__version__` and libraries you have installed on the virtual environment `pip freeze`

Comment: I run on Python 3.8.12 | packaged by conda-forge 
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin.
tensorflow version 2.6.0
GPU is properly installed. MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is also reported here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691917

I have seen the same issue myself and still wrapping my head around for a fix. So far one of the things that I found is that some people reported that similar issues are resolved if you use the latest macOS beta: **macOS 12.0+**, e.g.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50196#issuecomment-885031590 .
This is following the installation recommendation for tensorflow-metal, mentioned here:
https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Another ad-hoc which I tried and worked for me is to remove (or replace) the Adam optimizer.

Comment: It worked for me when I changed from Adam optimizer to SGD. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Small_J You're welcome, I am happy that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this all mac user M1 For all letest till macOs 13.0.2
I dropped back to the following versions: tensorflow-macos==2.9 and tensorflow-metal==0.5.0. Was using the tensorflow-macos==2.11 and tensorflow-metal==0.7.0 version and just couldn't get things to work. After dropping back I was able to use the GPU and all my validations worked. I'll check back later to see if a more current version will worl.